# Find a object inside a document by a field and retrive the object in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I'm using NodeJS to query MongoDB (4.4). I'm trying to figure how to search for a field inside an object inside a document and retrieve the object (or at least the `_id`). The field I'm querying by is the `created` field within the `transactions` document. How the table looks like is bellow.

[image]

I tried:

```
const result = await Model.findOne({}, { created: createdDate });
```

Didn't work. Never worked with these kinds of DB and am a bit lost. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

**Option 1:** ( Find )

```
db.collection.find({
  "transactions.created": "2022-12-21"
},
{
   transactions: {
      $elemMatch: {
        created: "2022-12-21"
      }
   }
})
```

Explained:

1. Find the document based on "transaction.created".
2. Project only the matching "transaction.created" object.

[playground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jbLHO3vT0Id)

**Option 2:** (Aggregation)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    "transactions.created": "2022-12-21"
  }
},
{
  $addFields: {
    transactions: {
     "$filter": {
       "input": "$transactions",
       "as": "t",
       "cond": {
         $eq: [
           "$$t.created",
           "2022-12-21"
         ]
        }
      }
     }
   }
  }
])
```

Explained:

1. Find the document based on transaction.created
2. Filter only the matched transaction created object.

[playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GbIpITX3HRr)

For best performance index need to be created on the "transaction.created" field.

Comment: Thank you very much @R2D2, option #1 did the trick